# Android - Revert View back to old position after view.animate() used for dragging

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, viewanimator

I have a view which I have to make it draggable. After the user leaves the drag it is to be animated down from current position. Now for dragging I have used the below code

```
 switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            rawY = event.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if ((event.getRawY() - rawY) < 0) {
                isDragging = false;
                return false;
            }
            isDragging = true;
            view.animate()
                    .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!isDragging) {
                return false;
            }
            animateContainer();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

The dragging is working fine, and after the container is animated down when user releases the drag. But when I press the button to open the container again it is not taking it's original height. It is back to last drag position.

What can I do to solve this. Thanks